# Checking in WiX if the OS is Windows 2003 (32 bit or 64 bit ) or Windows 2008 (64 bit)

Tags: wix

I am writing a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) installer which should install only on Windows 2003 (32 or 64 bit) or Windows 2008 (64 bit only). I have the below condition, but it isn't working. Why?

```
Installed AND (VersionNT = 502 OR (VersionNT = 600 AND VersionNT64 > 0))
```

Comment: To be honest, I try not to couple the installer so tightly to OS versions because a developer, tester or customer might have a valid reason for wanting to go outside the box.  Is there a specific dependency that you have in your application that requires these restractions?

Comment: @Christopher, it is because my boss wants me to do so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following condition:

```
VersionNT = 502 OR (VersionNT = 600 AND VersionNT64)
```

The first part selects Windows Server 2003 (any), the second part selects Windows Server 2008 x64 (as well as Windows Vista).

Your launch condition must evaluate to true for installer to launch. `Installed` property will be set only when your product is already installed.

---

You may want to include the check that your package is installed on a server OS:

```
MsiNTProductType > 1
```

---

See the table of [Operating System property values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370556%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). See description of [`MsiNTProductType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370329%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Similar to @Christopher, I would not recommend locking customers to specific versions of the OS. You already do not allow installing on Windows Server *2008 R2*. To overcome this restriction, users could [edit the MSI package](http://www.devcha.com/2007/01/edit-operating-system-version-check-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Platform="x64" />
```

Add the above code in Product.wxs file.
The number is calculated as major * 100 + minor. So 2.0 is 200, 3.0 is 300, 4.5 is 405 and 5.0 is 500.

Hence as per you requirement you can set the number in InstallVersion property